# Frama-C Gui on mavericks not working

Tags: ocaml, osx-mavericks, frama-c

Does anyone have installed Frama-C on Mavericks ?
Because i can't install it or do not know how to install it (Gui Version)!

### I already installed ocaml on my pc, but for the Gui version i need to install these libraries : Gtk, GtkSourceView, GnomeCanvas and Lablgtk2.

So i saw a previous post and did that :

```
export PKG_CONFIG_PATH=/opt/local/lib/pkgconfig
sudo port install opam
opam init
  Y
eval `opam config env`
sudo port install gtksourceview2 lablgtk2 ocaml-ocamlgraph
opam install frama-c
```

Im' having a problem in making "make" with frama-c which is :

```
Ocamlc       src/logic/property_status.cmo
File "src/logic/property_status.ml", line 1444, characters 4-2027:
Error: Signature mismatch:
   ...
   Values do not match:
     val vertex_attributes :
       v ->
       [> `Color of int
        | `Label of string
        | `Shape of [> `Box | `Diamond ]
        | `Style of [> `Bold | `Filled ] list
        | `Width of float ]
       list
   is not included in
     val vertex_attributes :
       V.t -> Graph.Graphviz.DotAttributes.vertex list
   File "src/logic/property_status.ml", line 1479, characters 16-33:
     Actual declaration
make: *** [src/logic/property_status.cmo] Error 2
```

How am i able to solve this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have successfully installed frama-c Neon with gui on mavericks using brew to get all the dependencies and using the source code in http://frama-c.com/download.html . If you try to do it using brew, you should install lablgtk from this repository(https://github.com/mht208/homebrew-formal) and only after all the other dependencies so the commands to install with gui would be(in source folder):

```
  brew install ocaml
  brew install gtk
  brew install gtksourceview
  brew install gnomecanvasmm gnomecanvas
  brew tap mht208/formal
  brew install lmht208/formal/lablgtk -with-gnomecanvas -with-gtksourceview2 
  ./configure
  make
```

You can also install ocamlgraph with opam, and you can compile Zarith and install in your system.

Comment: Thanks ! :)
I installed the Carbon version on mavericks which works and that's why i don't need it for now the Neon version !
But if it works, i really appreciate your answer for me and others who wanna install it on mavericks ! :)

Answer (score 4):

i've just successfully installed Frama-c neon (with Gui) on maverick, using opam and homebrew.

here's my walkthrough. (Thanks to tips above)

1) Install homebrew

```
$ruby -e "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.github.com/Homebrew/homebrew/go/install)"
```

2) Install opam:

```
$ brew install opam
$ opam init
```

(i had to modify .profile instead of .bashrc with f option)

```
$ eval `opam config env`
```

3) Install all dependencies

```
$ brew install gtk+
$ brew install gtksourceview
$ brew install libgnomecanvasmm libgnomecanvas
$ brew install lablgtk
```

4) Install Frama-c

```
$ export PKG_CONFIG_PATH=/usr/local/lib/pkgconfig
$ opam install frama-c
```

If you prefer install dependencies with macports, change the PKG_CONFIG_PATH to /opt/X11/lib/pkgconfig as explained [here](https://github.com/ocaml/opam-repository/pull/1435/files)

Hope this help

Comment: Tip: If you don't want all those dependencies (or the installation fails for some reason), try installing `frama-c-base` instead.

Answer (score 0):

`Graph.Graphviz` is from [OCamlGraph](https://github.com/backtracking/ocamlgraph). There seems to be an [incompatibility](https://github.com/backtracking/ocamlgraph/commit/98daafa8b09406b) between the two latest versions of each.

You'll have to add version contraints on the frama-c library, or change the Style attribute to have a list of the polymorphic variant set.

EDIT -

you don't need to install ocamlgraph via port, you should install that by opam as well.

Comment: And how can i do that ? :/

Comment: @Damiii, you are installing a couple of libraries using `port` command. Can you try to install them via opam? use `opam list -a| grep name` to get suitable opam packages' names

Comment: @Kakadu I believe that opam is for OCaml libraries. Am I wrong? In this case it would be perfectly normal to use MacPorts's `port` to install all the Gtk dependencies before starting to install the OCaml binding libraries. On the other hand, using `port` to install ocaml-ocamlgraph is probably not going to mix well with `opam`, (and MacPorts' packages are not up-to-date enough to provide OCamlgraph packages that are compatible with Frama-C. Better not install that and let Frama-C use the included OCamlgraph snapshot).

Comment: so i did these installations :
opam install lablgtk
opam install conf-gnomecanvas
opam install gtk-light
opam install lablgtk-extras
And didn't change anything :/

Comment: "... let Frama-C use the included OCamlgraph snapshot)." Which is ? Where do  i get that ?

Comment: ocamlgraph is also in OPAM, Damiii.

Comment: z$ opam install ocamlgraph
[NOTE] Package ocamlgraph is already installed (current version is 1.8.5).

Comment: looks like it's the issue I mentioned originally, and you need to have version 1.8.4 of ocamlgraph with frama-c currently. You can modify the opam file for frama-c in `.opam/repo/default/packages/frama-c/frama-c.20130601/opam` and add an additional constraint.

Comment: and how can i dowload that version ?

Comment: hmmm, i had no problem downloading and installing frama-c just now iva OPAM. I'm skeptical, something else may be happening here.

Comment: hummm the version on that file is : depends: [
  "ocamlgraph" {>= "1.8.3"}
  "lablgtk"
  "conf-gtksourceview"
  "conf-gnomecanvas"
]

Comment: And you have Mavericks ? :(

Comment: how did you manage to install it nlucaroni ?
Which commands have you done on mavericks ?

Comment: it wasn't on mavericks, but this isn't a mavericks issue. this is a version issue of those packages. `opam install frama-c`.

Comment: the opam install drama-c does work  ! but where is my GUI then ?

Comment: Doesn't appear on my terminal. Only frama-c

Comment: You might be missing gnomecanvas?

Comment: There is no such gnome canvas on opam

Comment: Nobody can helps me? :(

Comment: gnome-canvas is not provided by OPAM. OPAM currently only has OCaml packages. From the frama-c user manual installation section, "Gtk
-related packages: gtk+ version 2.4 or higher, GtkSourceView version 2.x, Gnome-Canvas version 2.x as well as LablGtk version 2.14 or higher are required for building the Graphical User Interface (GUI) of Frama-C." THen you have to reinstall frama-c, since the gui is an optional dependency.